# Prove Norm Theorems

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following as given:
Let $A \in C^{m\times m}$. Then:

1) $$\lVert A\rVert_1 =\sup_{v\in C^m \setminus\{0\} }{\lVert A_v\rVert_1 \over \lVert v\rVert_1} = \max_{j} \sum_i |a_{ij}|$$

How can I prove this? I read that you could use something like $\sum$?... Actually, doing a sum for some column elements and take the maximum one, but I have no ideea how. So my question is, how could I prove this?

2)$$\lVert A\rVert_\infty =\sup_{v\in C^m \setminus\{0\} }{\lVert A_v\rVert_\infty \over \lVert v\rVert_\infty} = \max_{i} \sum_j |a_{ij}|$$

Here is something like the first Theorem, but you have to take the max on lines? Again, is just something I've read, but couldn't understand quite well or prove anything.
3) $$\lVert A\rVert_2=\sup_{v\in C^m \setminus\{0\} }{\lVert A_v\rVert_2\over \lVert v\rVert_2} = \sqrt{\rho(AA^*)}=\sqrt{\rho(A^*A)}=\lVert A^*\rVert_2$$
if A is normal, $(AA^* = A^*A), then \lVert A\rVert_2=\rho(A)$

---

Was the starting ideea good, is there any way to prove this, or can anyone who knows help me solve the equations step by step and prove the theorems?
----------------------------------Update----------------------------------
I managed to prove the first (nr 1 equation and I now have nr2 and 3, written as I) and II) below).
I want to prove for example that:
I) $$\sup_{v\in C^m \setminus\{0\} }{\lVert A_v\rVert_2\over \lVert v\rVert_2} = \sqrt{\rho(AA^*)}=\sqrt{\rho(A^*A)}=\lVert A^*\rVert_2$$
if A is normal, $(AA^* = A^*A), then \lVert A\rVert_2=\rho(A)$
and
II) $$\lVert A\rVert_\infty =\sup_{v\in C^m \setminus\{0\} }{\lVert A_v\rVert_\infty \over \lVert v\rVert_\infty} = \max_{i} \sum_j |a_{ij}|$$

Comment: 1) For one direction, insert the standard unit vectors in $v$.

Comment: And then the norm would be 1?

Comment: Erm... no. Why should it?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html... Wouldn't it be $L_1$ norm? With the value of m? Meaning... If the matrix is m x m, as a $L_1$ norm, it would be m, right?

Comment: Of course, $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see the big picture. Where I have the $\sup$, I simply take v as 1? so it would be $$\sup_{v\in C^m \setminus\{0\} }{\lVert A_v\rVert_1 \over m}$$ ?

Comment: @achillehui, could you help me on this one? It is related to your top fields.

Comment: You have already chosen $v$. So, why do you write $\sup_{v\in C^m\setminus\{0\}}$? Anyway, I told you to put in the standard unit vectors for $v$, that is, $(1,0,\ldots,0)$, $(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, ... , $(0,\ldots,0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that good at algebra and I need to remember some things and reread them. So the unit vector in a $C^m$ space would be just as you wrote? and $v_i$ would have 0 everywhere and 1 on the $i$ position? Then how do you calculate the norm for this, I thought that I got it right in the beginning, but now, as I remember things, I see I did not. Maybe you could write it as an answer and I could also accept it?

Comment: I do not like to "serve" complete answers. For example, put in $v = (1,0,\ldots,0)$ into $\|Av\|_1/\|v\|_1$. What do you get?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp, YES! So you could help me deduct the answer? :) great! for now I got to go a couple hours.

Comment: Oooooow... Av = first column from A since v is treated as column vector?

Comment: Regarding the $\sup$... It takes the highest value from $\lVert Av\rVert$ ? And $\lVert Av\rVert$ is actually the sum of elements from each column?

Comment: Forget about the sup for the moment. You have not answered my last question.

Comment: Didn't I answer? The sum of elements from the first column in A.

Comment: Correct. Do that for any other standard basis vector. It then follows that the sup is $\ge$ the RHS.